# How to confirm if user has pressed on a button in pysimplegui

Tags: python-3.8, pysimplegui

I want the `Predict Risk` button to work only if one of the above buttons have been pressed before.

The code for the ui is as follows:

```
layout=[[sg.Text('Choose the Industry')],
        [sg.Button("Automobile"),sg.Button("Chemical"),sg.Button("Engineering/Consulting"),
        sg.Button("FMCG"),sg.Button("Healthcare/Hospitality"),sg.Button("Infrastructue")],
        [sg.Button("IT/Comm/DC"),sg.Button("Manufacturing"),sg.Button("Mines"),
        sg.Button("Energy/Oil & Gas"),sg.Button("Pharma"),sg.Button("Retail"),sg.Button("Cement")],
        [sg.Text(size=(50,1),key=('loaded'))],
        [sg.Text('Enter Observation/Recommendation: ', size =(26, 1)), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Button("Predict Risk")],
        [sg.Text(size=(30,1),key=('output'))],
        [sg.Text('If the above prediction is correct select \'yes\' else select the correct risk.')],
        [sg.Button("Yes"),sg.Button("Low"),sg.Button("Medium")],
        #[sg.Text('Select the correct risk: '),sg.Button("Low"),sg.Button("Medium")],
        [sg.Text(size=(30,2),key=('trained'))],
        [sg.Button("Exit"),sg.Button("Clear Fields")]
]

window=sg.Window("Risk Predictor",layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    #obs=values[0]
    # End program if user closes window or
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break

window.close()
```

The above code is not complete.

I want the rest of application to be active only when the one of the top buttons has been pressed.
Secondly is there a way to map the enter key with `Predict Risk` button so user can just hit enter and get the prediction.

[image: User interface of the application]

Comment: Why not use `sg.Radio` for choosing all above buttons ? Set option `bind_return_key=True` in `sg.Button`, the return key will cause this button to be pressed.

Comment: When any of the above buttons is pressed the model and relevant data set is loaded and then only I want the ```Predict Risk``` button to work. Currently if I write ```if event='Mines': if event='Predict Risk': #prediction function gets called```doesn't work. I realise both buttons cannot be pressed at the same time but how do I make sure the industry is selected before predicting risk. I thought about radio button but I dont think its a good idea in this case. Is there another way to make sure the button is pressed?

Comment: How is this a machine learning question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables or attribute `button.metadata` to record the state `clicked` for buttons. Initial value for each button is set by option `metadata=False` in `sg.Button` means not yet clicked. When button clicked, `button.metadata` will be set to `True`, it means this button clicked.

Here show the way to record the clicked state in button.metadata.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

items = [
    "Automobile", "Chemical", "Engineering/Consulting", "FMCG",
    "Healthcare/Hospitality", "Infrastructue", "IT/Comm/DC", "Manufacturing",
    "Mines", "Energy/Oil & Gas", "Pharma", "Retail", "Cement",
]
length = len(items)
size = (max(map(len, items)), 1)

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 11))

column_layout = []
line = []
num = 4
for i, item in enumerate(items):
    line.append(sg.Button(item, size=size, metadata=False))
    if i%num == num-1 or i==length-1:
        column_layout.append(line)
        line = []

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Choose the Industry')],
    [sg.Column(column_layout)],
    [sg.Text(size=(50,1),key=('loaded'))],
    [sg.Text('Enter Observation/Recommendation: ', size =(26, 1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Button("Predict Risk", bind_return_key=True)],
    [sg.Text(size=(30,1),key=('output'))],
    [sg.Text('If the above prediction is correct select \'yes\' else select the correct risk.')],
    [sg.Button("Yes"),sg.Button("Low"),sg.Button("Medium")],
    [sg.Text(size=(30,2),key=('trained'))],
    [sg.Button("Exit"),sg.Button("Clear Fields")]
]

window=sg.Window("Risk Predictor", layout, use_default_focus=False, finalize=True)
for key in window.key_dict:    # Remove dash box of all Buttons
    element = window[key]
    if isinstance(element, sg.Button):
        element.block_focus()

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event in items:
        window[event].metadata = True
    elif event == "Predict Risk" and window["Mines"].metadata:
        print("Predict Risk for Mines")

window.close()
```

Comment: I am sorry but could you please explain it a little.

Comment: You can use variables or attribute `button.metadata` to record the state `clicked` for buttons. Initial value for each button is set by option `metadata=False` in `sg.Button` means not yet clicked. When button clicked, `button.metadata` will be set to `True`, it means this button clicked.

Comment: Ohh ok. Just one more clarification. in line```elif event == "Predict Risk" and window["Mines"].metadata:``` it is checking if metadata for that particular button is true or not right? And shouldn't it be ```window['Mines'].metadata=True:```?

Comment: `window["Mines"].metadata` is a bool value, so it is used in `if..elif...else` statement directly, the same as `window["Mines"].metadata == True`.   It is checking if metadata for that particular button is true, or clikced. `window['Mines'].metadata=True` is assignment statement, not for if statement.

Comment: I typed it wrong. But I got it. Thank you